# python: how to save physically the xml file after change

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have this code :

country.xml :

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
<rank>1</rank>
<year>2008</year>
<gdppc>141100</gdppc>
<neighbor direction="E" name="Austria"/>
<neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland"/>
```

and :

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('country.xml')
print(xmldoc.toxml())
country = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("country")
firstchild = country[0]
print(firstchild.attributes["name"].value)
firstchild.attributes["name"].value = "Germany"
print(xmldoc.toxml())
```

the document has changed the name of the country from:
"Liechtenstein"
TO
"Germany"

My question is how to save the change back to the country.xml file ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply open the file and write the output of `xmldoc.toxml()` to it. Example -

```
...
with open('country.xml','w') as f:
    f.write(xmldoc.toxml())
```